# Converting String to int in java

Tags: java

I need to convert a string to a corresponding int array in java. i wrote the following code but its not working as i expected .

```
        String temp= "abc1";
        int[] intArray = new int[temp.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
            intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
        }
```

I have written an rc4 encryption program which take the key and plain text as int arrays. So I need to convert the user specified key to int array before passing it to the encryption function. Is this the correct way of using key in encryption programs?

Comment: What do you expect when converting 'a' to int? A hexadecimal value? The ASCII code?

Comment: You not getting any exception?

Comment: Why don't you use the built-in RC4 algorithm of the JDK? And why use ints instead of bytes?

Comment: int result = Integer.parseInt(temp);

Comment: temp is a string ...not an array...Even if it were an array of strings..you would get a NumberFormatException

Comment: @Heuster - ASCII code.

the code is not working.

Comment: "_Is this the correct way[...]?_" **No**, it has compiler errors, so no, it is not the correct way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443975/how-can-i-get-ascii-value-at-input-word

Answer (score 3):

Use this to get the ASCII code

```
intArray[i] = (int)temp.charAt(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert string to charArray. Travesing charArray you can convert as:

```
char[] c = inputString.toCharArray()
for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
     int n    = Integer.parseInt(c[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are Using Java8 or higher then it might be helpful for you

```
String temp="abc1";
int[] intArray =temp.chars().map(x->x-'0').toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray ));
```

int array would be [49, 50, 51, 1]

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by using byte instead of int. Modified the rc4 to take byte array.
converted the string to byte using

```
    String Nkey = jTextField2.getText();
    jTextField3.setText(Nkey);
    int i;
    byte[] key = Nkey.getBytes();
```