# How to convert ArrayList Chararcter elements to Integer

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Character> a = new ArrayList<Character>();
a.add('A');
a.add('B');
a.add('C');
ArrayList<Integer> s = (ArrayList<Integer>) a.clone();
System.out.println("Character: " + a + "\n Integer: " + s);
```

I need the answer as:

> Character: [A, B, C]
>   Integer: [65, 66, 67]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443975/get-ascii-value-at-input-word

Comment: Please check you print statement syntax, if you are writing correct or not.. You are missing "+" before "a" in the statement.

Comment: You just need to convert between `char` and `int`.  This is a straightforward thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this way.

```
List<Character> a=new ArrayList<Character>();
a.add('A');
a.add('B');
a.add('C');

List<Integer> s= new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(Character i:a){
   s.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
}

System.out.println("Character: "+a +"\nInteger: "+s);
```

Out put:

```
Character: [A, B, C]
Integer: [65, 66, 67]
```

Comment: @darijan why don't you try? please try this your own.

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to convert it into `int`.

```java
ArrayList<Integer> s = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(Character c: a) {
    s.add((int) c)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int charCode = (int) c.charValue();
```

In your example

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(Character c : a) {
    result.add((int) c.charValue());
}
```